# Сервер не видит псевдоним пути

Tags: yii

Здраствуйте. Задаю путь к картинке через псевдоним пути  `<img src="' . ('/' . Yii::getPathOfAlias('photos') . '/' . $data->photo) . '"` На локальном опенсервере все работает хорошо, но при заливке на хостинг видит только `$data->photo`, псевдоним пути пуст. В чем проблема? Спасибо

Comment: Надо смотреть ошибки (в логах к примеру). Ваш  К.О.

Comment: В логах - системе не удалось найти указаный путь